# HTML - Open a Table inside a Table when click

Tags: html

I have a table with 2 columns and 2 rows like this
[image]

I would like to make the elements of the first column clickable and when one clicks on it, it appears another table under that row.

[image]

I thought of adding an `href` but this doesnt work:

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva">
  <table id="tableInfo" data-role=table class="ui-responsive" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <a href=#info1 >
       <table id="tableInfoNested1" data-role=table class="ui-responsive" width="100%">
       <tbody>
         <tr>Address</tr>
         <tr>City</tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>
       Name
     </a>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <a href=#info2 >
       <table id="tableInfoNested2" data-role=table class="ui-responsive" width="100%">
       <tbody>
         <tr>Test</tr>
         <tr>Test</tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>
       Code
     </a>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<a id="LogicLink" onclick="Table1();" href="#">Name</a>
<table id="TableNested1"  style="display:none">
<tr><td>Adresss<td/><tr/>
    <tr><td>City<td/><tr/>
<table/>

 <br/>       
<a id="Link" onclick="Table2();" href="#">Code</a>
<table id="TableNested2" style="display:none">
<tr><td>Test<td/><tr/>
    <tr><td>Test<td/><tr/>
</table>     

 function Table1()
{
     var elem=document.getElementById("TableNested1");
     var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
     if (hide) {
         elem.style.display="table";
    } 
    else {
       elem.style.display="none";
    }
  }

    function Table2()
   {
     var elem=document.getElementById("TableNested2");
     var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
     if (hide) {
         elem.style.display="table";
    } 
    else {
       elem.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wfxpu/180/

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>

       <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Collapsible Lists</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <h2>My Phonebook</h2>
         <div data-role="collapsible">
          <h4>A</h4>
          <ul data-role="listview">
           <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>

         <div data-role="collapsible">
          <h4>B</h4>
          <ul data-role="listview">
           <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>

         <div data-role="collapsible">
         <h4>C</h4>
         <ul data-role="listview">
          <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cameron</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chloe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
         <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
        </div>
       </div> 

      </body>
     </html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_collapsible
OR
http://jasalguero.com/ledld/development/web/expandable-list/

You will have to apply the same principle to your table